# Sed breaking during git filter-branch

Tags: android, git, sed, android-studio, git-filter-branch

Has anyone successfully modified files in an Android Studio project throughout the repository history?  I'm trying to remove some sensitive data that was entered mistakenly and spans several commits (it's a phone number).  I'm attempting to run the following command:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/xxxxxxxxxx/0000000000/g'"
```

But I'm immediately getting the error

```
Rewrite c61760bca0273b8597299146fa5c43f984a50e3c (1/22)sed: can't read : No such file or directory
tree filter failed: find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/xxxxxxxxxx/0000000000/g'
```

where xxxxxxxxxx is the number to be switched out.  The files in question are stored in a deeper directory, but for some reason sed can't even find them.  I'm guessing the error means it fails on the first commit because sed can't read the files?  I'm unsure why, because they are definitely local.

Can anyone shed some light on my trouble?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `-print0` requires `xargs -0`.

Comment: @sputnick There are file names. `xargs` provides them.

Comment: @EtanReisner Using `xargs -0` gave me the same error.

Comment: Oh, you probably need `-r` for `xargs` also to not run when there isn't any input.

Comment: Progress! Now it's claiming it can't find the file '' (doesn't even have the quotation marks, it's looking for a blank file I think) and it fails on commit 3 instead of 1.

Comment: If you add `| tee OUT` to that pipeline what do you see in that file? Any blank lines? What does the tree in the commit it is failing on look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about obscure flags if you use [the BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), rather than `git-filter-branch`. The BFG is designed specifically for the case of remove unwanted data- where you don't really care *where* the bad data is, in what obscure file - you just want it gone.

To use the BFG, create a `unwanted.txt` file, containing just one line like this:

```bsh
xxxxxxxxxx==>0000000000
```

Then [run the BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) with this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar -fi '*.java' --replace-text unwanted.txt  my-repo.git
```

Your entire repository history will be scanned, and all `.java` files (under 1MB in size) will have the substitutions performed: any matching string (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be replaced.

The BFG is typically [hundreds of times faster](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#speed) than running `git-filter-branch` on a big repo and the options are tailored around these two common use-cases:

- Removing **Crazy Big Files**
- Removing **Passwords, Credentials** & other **Private data**

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: It works--partly.  It claims that there are "no refs to update - no dirty commits found??"

Comment: Err--nevermind, sorry.  It worked more now.  Except it's still saying `! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)` when I run git push.  Any idea?

Comment: Fixed it!  I think it worked.  Marking as answer, thanks a ton.